# PHP SDK - Post Image to facebook fan page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I have a file url (http://example.com/image.jpg) and I need to make an image post to a facebook fan page (already have the access token).

What is the best way to do this with the facebook PHP SDK?

It seams like I will need to some how load the image and then some how post it as multipart/form-data according to [the api docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#photos)

Comment: No, you can also use the parameter `url` with the publicly reachable HTTP address of your image, instead of the `source` parameter, and send it as a normal POST request. (Mentioned here in last sentence of introduction: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/)

Comment: That seems to be info for postings to a users wall not a fan page. The docs differ fan pages.

Comment: It works for pages as well. And @filepath is for _real_ HTTP POST uploads using cURL (explicitly or implicitly by using the FB PHP SDK). With the `url` parameter you just pass the value `http://example.com/image.jpg`, nothing else. (Apart from message, title, …)

Comment: Interesting that the docs dont mention being able to do this for the fan pages. So I just need to make a normal post but specify a url param when making the call and all should be good?

Comment: posting to /PAGE_ID/photos with a url param does indeed work. Please post your solution as an answer so I may accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can also use the parameter `url` with the publicly reachable HTTP address of your image, instead of the `source` parameter, and send it as a normal POST request. (Mentioned here in last sentence of introduction: developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo)

> That seems to be info for postings to a users wall not a fan page. The docs differ fan pages.

It works for pages as well. And @filepath is for real HTTP POST uploads using cURL (explicitly or implicitly by using the FB PHP SDK). With the `url` parameter you just pass the value `http://example.com/image.jpg`, nothing else. (Apart from message, title, …)